# How to capture output from bourne shell command

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to execute a bourne shell command, capture its stdout and its stderr (separately), as well as its exit code.

Comment: Thats for stdout and stderr..!!
is exit_code should also be captured in the similar way? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subprocess (part of stdlib):

```
import subprocess

cmd = input("enter your command: " )
result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
print("stdout = %s" % (result.stdout))
print("stderr = %s" % (result.stderr))
print("return = %d" % (result.returncode))
```

Comment: Yep. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess